# VBA - Outlook 2010 - Using ReceivedTime of email in calculation constrained by work week and office hours

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to develop a module in Outlook that can use the ReceivedTime of an email and then add x hours to it to give a 'response time'. The hours added though have to be within the working week (Mon-Fri) and the office hours (9-5).

For my case, x can be declared a constant of 36 hours, however (as below) I don't know how to write the code for this with the constraints of the work week and office hours.

I was able to write a basic module that adds 100 hours, as this can give the correct response time in some cases.

```
Sub TargetResolution()
Dim myMail As Outlook.MailItem

For Each myMail In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

Dim LDate As Date

LDate = DateAdd("h", 100, myMail.ReceivedTime)

MsgBox "Time Received: " & (myMail.ReceivedTime) & Chr(13) & "Target Resolution: " & (LDate)
Next

Set myMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: You should be able to use the `Workweek` function in VBA. You may need to add some additional logic to control office hours.  Here is a list of some date/time functions in VBA: http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdatetime.html

Comment: Hi David, thank you for that, I had come across these functions before but it is the logic part where I'm struggling, I'm quite new to scripting/coding so this is a bit above me at the moment. I'll keep at it!

Comment: What are the constraints for the workweek/office hours? Right now you have an arbitrary addition of "100 hours" which is probably not what you want. If you can revise your question to clarify, e.g., "A response should always be given within 2 working days" or something like that, I can probably help set up the logic.

Comment: Hi David, to clarify the calculation is producing a time by which our team has should have an issue resolved by. So for example, an incident email may come in at 3:23 PM on a Tuesday, adding 36 business hours, the issue resolution should be completed by the next Tuesday at 11:23 AM. The constraints would be exclude weekends, and each week day is 8 hours between 9am-5pm. This would mean that an email received at for example, 7:36 AM on a Wednesday the calculation would be made from 9 AM that morning, giving a resolution time of 1 PM the following Tuesday. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so to do this you're going to need to work with some of the Date & Time functions I mentioned above. I am not certain this will account for Holidays -- actually, I'm pretty sure it will not, since those vary by locale, and even by business. In any case this should get you 99% of the way there:

You should be able to call this function in your macro by:

`LDate = GetTargetDate(myMail.ReceivedTime, 36)`

I include a test subroutine, so you can plug in a date/time and see what results:

```
Sub TestDate()
    Dim dt As Date

    dt = "6/1/2013 12:06:00 PM"

    Debug.Print "Received at " & dt
    Debug.Print "Due by " & GetTargetDate(dt, 36)

End Sub
```

Here is the function, place it within your code module:

```
Option Explicit
Const startDay As String = " 9:00:00 AM"
Const endDay As String = " 5:00:00 PM"
Const hrsPerDay As Long = 8
Function GetTargetDate(myDate As Date, numHours As Long) As Date
    Dim effRecdDate As Date
    Dim newDate As Date
    Dim resolveDays As Double 'number of hours, converted to full days
    Dim resolveHours As Long
    Dim hh As Long

    resolveDays = numHours / hrsPerDay 'convert to days

    '## Ensure the timestamp is within business hours
    effRecdDate = ValidBizHours(myDate)

    '## Ensure the date is a business day
    effRecdDate = ValidWeekday(myDate)

    'Convert to hours, carrying the partial day as a fraction of the 8-hr workday
    resolveHours = (Int(resolveDays) * 24) + numHours Mod hrsPerDay

    '## Add each of the resolveHours, but if the result is not a weekday, then
    ' add another day
    For hh = 1 To resolveHours
        newDate = DateAdd("h", hh, effRecdDate)
        If Weekday(newDate, vbMonday) > 5 Then
            effRecdDate = DateAdd("d", 1, effRecdDate)
        End If
    Next

    '## Make sure this date falls between biz hours AND that
    ' it consequently falls on a business DAY
    Do
        If TimeValue(newDate) > TimeValue(startDay) And TimeValue(newDate) < TimeValue(endDay) Then
            If Weekday(newDate, vbMonday) <= 5 Then
                Exit Do
            Else:
                newDate = DateAdd("d", 1, newDate)
            End If
        Else:
            newDate = DateAdd("h", 1, newDate)
        End If
    Loop

    '## Return the newDate to the function:
    GetTargetDate = newDate
End Function
Private Function ValidWeekday(myDate As Date) As Date
    'Converts timestamps received on the weekend to Monday morning, 9:00:00 AM
    Do While Weekday(myDate, vbMonday) > 5
        myDate = DateValue(DateAdd("d", 1, myDate)) & startDay
    Loop
    ValidWeekday = myDate
End Function

Private Function ValidBizHours(myDate As Date) As Date
    'Converts timestamps after business hours to 9:00:00 AM the following day
    'Converts timestamps before business hours to 9:00:00 AM same business day
    Select Case TimeValue(myDate)
        Case Is > TimeValue(endDay)
            'Assume this is received at start of the following day:
            myDate = DateValue(DateAdd("d", 1, myDate)) & startDay
        Case Is < TimeValue(startDay)
            'Assume this is received at start of day, but not earlier:
            myDate = DateValue(myDate) & startDay
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
    ValidBizHours = myDate
End Function
```

This yields the following:

If email is received during business hours:

```
Received at 5/27/2013 9:06:00 AM
Due by 5/31/2013 1:06:00 PM
```

If email is received during business hours, but the deadline becomes after business hours or on weekend, carry the remainder :

```
Received at 5/30/2013 1:06:00 PM
Due by 6/6/2013 9:06:00 AM
```

If a mail is received before business hours, consider it received at 9:00:00 AM :

```
Received at 5/27/2013 7:06:00 AM
Due by 5/31/2013 1:00:00 PM
```

If a mail is received after business hours, consider it received at 9:00:00 AM the following business day:

```
Received at 5/27/2013 9:06:00 PM
Due by 6/3/2013 1:00:00 PM
```

And also works if the mail is received on the weekend, consider it received at 9:00:00 AM on Monday:

```
Received at 6/1/2013 12:06:00 PM
Due by 6/7/2013 1:00:00 PM
```

Comment: Hi David, that is amazing, more than I would have been able to do! I have put it into the module and the the macro is calling the function, and returning the correct date, however the time is still stuck on the  startDay constant, so all emails that I'm running the macro on are giving the correct date but time as "9:00:00 AM". Is that because it is set to a string? Thank you very much again

Comment: I've been able to add a reference to the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Library and copy LDate to clipboard as well, I'm learning a lot through this!

Comment: No something was not right in my function, try the revision, above :)

Comment: Sorry David, this doesn't work either, the startDay constant is still staying at 9:00:00 AM in the output?

Comment: Try changing to `Dim resolveDays As Double`, it should not be an integer. Although I'm not certain that is going to fix what you're asking for.

Comment: that should fix part of it. still not correctly adding dates across the weekend, though.

Comment: I was able to fix the weekend issue by modifying `myDate = dateValue(DateAdd("d", 2, myDate))` in the cases. The only problem now is trying to get the calculated time (hh:mm:ss) to show in the output instead of the startDay string

Comment: See my revision, above. It is my understanding that any email received before 9am will be considered received *at* 9:00 AM, and that mail received after 5pm will be considered received at 9am the following business day. That is why the 9:00AM might persist.

Comment: Hi David, your understanding is correct, however the examples seem to be adding 4 days (32 hours) and not 36 hours, eg. Received at 5/28/2013 12:06:00 PM Due by 6/3/2013 4:06:00 PM and eg. Received at 5/27/2013 7:06:00 AM Due by 5/31/2013 1:00:00 PM. Looking at it I think it's because the DateAdd is being calculated using days and not hours? I tried to fix it myself but couldn't, many thanks again David :)

Comment: OK. The `DateAdd` function looks like it should take a `Double` precision value for `resolveDays` and we are passing `4.5` for this value, which is a `Double`, but it's still treating it like a long/integer, `4`.  I can fix this by converting everything to hours, but then you have to do another round of checks to see if the new time is a valid business hour. More than I have time for tonight, but I can try to play with it tomorrow morning.

Comment: See revision, appears to be working for the test cases I plug in.

Comment: Thank you very much David, that is absolutely fantastic, has made my day! All the best!

Comment: You're quite welcome --  this was pretty tricky, and although I'm almost certain there are *better* or more efficient ways of doing this, it was an interesting Q for me to work on.